# Next js in subfolder /blog change index.js file for example to _blog_index.js?

Tags: next.js

in subfolder /blog can i change index.js file for example to _blog_index.js and it will be read as index.js?

each subfolder has index.js file and sometime is difficult to read in code editor, when i have many subfolders and many tabs open.

Thank u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible when using [`rewrites()`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites) in `next.config.js`:

```js
const nextConfig = {
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: "/blog",
        destination: "/blog/_blog_index",
      },
    ];
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

However, keep in mind that `rewrites()` [won't be supported](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export#unsupported-features) if you're planning to [export your app to static HTML](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export) because it requires a Node.js server.